# how do i combine a list of dictionaries into a single dictionary?

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary which contains a list of dictionaries. How do I split them ?

## Input

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Hashtags' : [{u'indices': [53, 65], u'text': u'Predictions'}, {u'indices': [67, 76], u'text': u'FreeTips'}, {u'indices': [78, 89], u'text': u'SoccerTips'}, {u'indices': [90, 103], u'text': u'FootballTips'}, {u'indices': [104, 110], u'text': u'Goals'}]})
```

## Expected Output :

```
{'Hashtags' :["u'Predictions'", "u'SoccerTips'", "u'FootballTips'", "u'Goals'"]}
```

Comment: Does it matter that it's in a data frame?

Comment: @asongtoruin That question has no answers. It cannot be considered a duplicate.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder What makes you think that? It can be a duplicate even if neither question has answers. :)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder it's the same question posted twice - seems the definition of "duplicate" to me.

Comment: @MSeifert, really sorry, for posting this again. I assumed that question didn't reach anyone, or people ignored it. So i asked same thing again.

Comment: @Coldspeed, Anyways, actually, when whole data is considered, it is a pandas series. Not a dictionary or a dataframe, but for simplicity i've converted it into one.

Comment: @lightyagami96 In that case it's often better to just edit the original question to make it more clear or show what progress you made on your own to tackle the problem. :) By the way, I actually answered the original, you might want to take a look. Leave a comment there if it's not working :)

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Hashtags' : [{u'indices': [53, 65], u'text': u'Predictions'}, {u'indices': [67, 76], u'text': u'FreeTips'}, {u'indices': [78, 89], u'text': u'SoccerTips'}, {u'indices': [90, 103], u'text': u'FootballTips'}, {u'indices': [104, 110], u'text': u'Goals'}]})

texts = [x['text'] for x in df.values.flatten()]

output = {'Hashtags': texts }
```

Comment: I've tried it already, its giving me the following error : `df2=pd.read_csv('final.csv')
datas=df2.Hashtags
texts = [xz['text'] for xz in datas.values.flatten()]

output = {'Hashtags': texts }
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-160-15004657b9ea>", line 3, in <module>
    texts = [xz['text'] for xz in datas.values.flatten()]

TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`